# Error when trying to load an image

Tags: android, image

I have the following error when trying to load an image. jpeg (1856x1044 and 687kb) in a gallery:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

I have a ImageAdapter and in the method getView() i have:

```
imageview.setImageResource(images[position]); --> here it fails
```

As I can treat the image so that it does not fail?

Comment: In your Device there will be different resolution types of Images. So Sometimes if some image has low resolution it will be set your ImageView but some has a high Resolution type so it will be taken a time to load because of high-resolution. So it may be problem for that.

Comment: How many images in your **images** array??

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with large bitmaps in Android is not a simple task. You can read about it here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deploy your app in Emulator, edit the emulator (before deploying) and then increase the VM heap of the device.

Comment: I'm trying to test on my device, the emulator runs ok